# Problem tracking outbound links using TagManager

Tags: google-tag-manager, tracking, outbound, clickstream

Hope somebody can help me.
I'm a newby and have a website, using Google Analytics.
I now want to track outbound links from my website to a third party website.

Based on what I found on internet, I have set up tag manager, sas you can see here:
https://saskiahermans.nl/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/TagManager.docx

However, after a few days I can't find any outbound clicks back in Google Analytics, where I'm sure there have been some.

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody please help?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't very helpful ... I'm still struggling with tracking the outbound links ... Please help ... and if you need more or different information, please tell me.

Comment: show screenshots of your implementation as well as screenshots of the GTM preview debugger.

Comment: In the link I posted earlier, you can see the implementation.

On https://saskiahermans.nl/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/tag-manager-debug.png you see the debug output.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: that's a docx, please post images of the actual implementation you've made. Also click on the tag not fired on your event, then scroll down to its trigger and make a screenshot.

Comment: Here they are: 

https://saskiahermans.nl/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/var.png
https://saskiahermans.nl/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/tag.png
https://saskiahermans.nl/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/link-click.png

Not sure how to fulfill yu latest request. My problem is that I can't find the outbound links back in any of my GA-reports.

Comment: my latest is not about GA but GTM preview

Comment: I appreciate your help. Not sure if I get you. 

I’ve defined a variable, trigger, and tag to track outbound links (screenshots above). 

In debug mode I can see the outbound links being clicked.

I want to see a report with the links being clicked (by visitors of my website). Where can I find it or what do I need to do to find these. I don't know of any tag not being fired etc.  
An example of a page with links I want to be tracked is at the bottom of https://saskiahermans.nl/spelenderwijs/3-2-bieden-met-fit/ with links to third party software behind ‘quiz’ and behind ‘oefenspellen’.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after debugging it in comments and looking at the actual tracking, here what is sent to GA4 on outbound clicks on the site in question:

```
en: "click",
ep.link_id: "",
ep.link_classes: "",
ep.link_url: <URL>,
ep.link_domain: <domain>,
ep.outbound: "true",
```

Well this is plenty.
Now go to your GA4 property, `Admin` -> `Custom Definitions` (under the Property) -> Make sure your eps (event parameters) are registered as custom dimensions. Like so:

[image]

You probably want to do that for the `ep.outbound` and `ep.link_domain`. Don't do it for the link_url. Url can be too high-cardinality for GA4 to handle.

After you're done with defining custom dimensions, give it time to gather data and filter into the custom dimensions (about a day) and go to your Explorer, click the + sign in Dimensions and add your custom dimensions to the list. Now just pull the dimensions and metrics you're interested in into the report and they all should be good.

If you still don't see the dimensions filled, make sure your measurement id in the tracking `tid: "G-V24L72RLMM"` is the same as in the `Admin` -> `Data Streams`. It's a popular mistake when people send data in a wrong analytics property.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can now find them! Great!!